# Programmatically hide all other active applications Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to make a OS X application that automatically hides "⌘H, not minimize" all other applications when it is launched, and I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have for accomplishing this so far...

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.Developer.myApp"
                                                         options:NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHideOthers
                                  additionalEventParamDescriptor:NULL
                                                launchIdentifier:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[ [ NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace ] hideOtherApplications ];
```

[NSWorkspace class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Note: if your `awakeFromNib` method is executed, it means your application is launched.
So trying to launch it again won't work.